# Symfony 2.2 - bad redirect after login in dev environment

Tags: forms, security, redirect, symfony, authentication

After setting up Symfony2.2, I have the following code in my login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{path('rok_admin_default_index')}}"/>
```

Where `rok_admin_default_index` is pointing to "/" so it's basically the homepage of the application. During the development I'm using `app_dev.php` (which I obviously), but after successful login in dev environment Symfony redirects me to **domain.com/app_dev.php/app_dev.php/** instead of **domain.com/app_dev.php/**

My security.yml:

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        ROK\AdminBundle\Entity\User: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MOD: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_MOD, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: ROK\AdminBundle\Entity\User, property: email }
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                mod: {password: modpass, roles: ['ROLE_MOD']}
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin/
        form_login:
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: login
        logout: ~
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symfony2 documentation says

> The value attribute can be a relative path, absolute URL, or a route
>   name.

So we can try the second and third options

Use absolute path

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{url('rok_admin_default_index')}}"/>
```

Or Use route name

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="rok_admin_default_index"/>
```